# How to get selected item data from datagrid WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selecteditem

Hello i want to get data from selected item. I tried datagrid.selectedItem.ToString() but it doesnt get data from selected item.

Comment: Show the essential parts of your code as an edit of your question.

Comment: SelectedItem is itself a data you want....

Answer (score 0):

simple way would be:

```
var selected = datagrid.SelectedItem;
```

but you could also use binding and MVVM when doing WPF